# Would it be on-topic to ask why few (if any) Japanese manga artists license their characters out to other artists?

Tags: discussion

Being a fan of both Western comics and Japanese manga, I notice that a massive difference is that Western artists like Stan Lee will create a character and then allow other people to write stories based on their character (in exchange for royalty fees). Japanese artists never do that, and that's probably the reason why most manga series end while Western superheros have been going strong for decades.

I've never quite understood why this is so. It would appear to be profitable for Kishi to license the Naruto universe to other artists, and let it grow and go on forever. Is there some reason most artists don't do this?

Comment: Are you talking about the practice of spin-off series by different artist? It's a perfectly valid "manga-production" question. I believe that it's usually handled by the company that contracts the author I believe, with some input by the author. Sometimes the author does multiple series at once, like the author or Magi and the Sinbad spinoff.

Comment: Heh, are you asking if you can ask it, or are you asking it? In any case, yes, this question is on-topic. Would you like it moved to the main site?

Comment: Great! I wasn't sure, so I posted the full question here. I'll rephrase it and add examples tonight, then I'll ask it in the main section. Thanks!